# How to set up a Todo List to receive and send SMS with Twilio

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio

TwilioQuest

Build a small web application to power our To-do Bot. Your bot should receive a text message, look at the message's body, and then respond with a confirmation SMS to one of three commands: "add {{ thing to do }}" - The add command should add a thing to the to-do list. For example, "add buy milk" should add an item named "buy milk" "list" - The list command should return every item on the to-do list in a numbered list. A list of two items would return "1. Buy milk 2. Wash clothes" "remove #" - The remove command should remove an item from the to-do list based on its position in the list. So "remove 2" would remove the "Wash clothes" item from above To complete this objective, add an item to your to-do list called "Complete this objective." Your to-do app should reply with an SMS confirming that the item has been added. Then give us the phone number for your To-do Bot below.

I am using NodeJS for this twilio tutorial and I am not sure how to set up the numbered list and remove list. I have set this up so far

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  if (req.body.Body == 'add') {
    twiml.message('buy milk');
...
...
    );
  }

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
});
```

--need to come up with this---
Create a new variable in your web application to store our user's to-dos. For this exercise, don't worry about making your bot support more than one user at a time.

Alter the "/sms" route in your web app to look at the first word in each incoming text message and see if it matches any of our commands
If the command is "add", then add the remainder of the message body as an entry in your to-do list variable.

If the command is "list", then respond to the text message with a numbered list of every item in your to-do list variable.

If the command is "remove", then use the number the user specified to remove that item from the to-do list variable.

**I need help on how to set up the list and remove command for my todo list bot**

Comment: Please provide a question or problem you are trying to solve.  From what I see, this is just a copy and paste of a spec.

Comment: so what I am trying to solve is how to set up the list and remove command, I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look something like this:

```
var itemList = [];

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

    const splitContent = req.body.Body.split(' ');

    switch (splitContent[0]) {
        case 'add':
            itemList.push(splitContent.slice(1).join(' ')); // Slice 1 to start at the second item
            twiml.message('Item added');
            break;
        case 'list':
            var result = ''
            var i = 1;
            itemList.forEach(o => {
                result += `${i}. ${o}\n`;
                i++;
            });
            twiml.message(result);
            break;
        case 'remove':
            itemList.splice(splitContent[1] - 1, 1); // Subtract 1 to get the index
            twiml.message('Item removed');
            break;
    }

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```